# Usb flash drive doesn't show up on Bios Boot Manager

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, uefi

I'm having some troubles with reinstalling ubuntu on my Acer Aspire E15 laptop.

I made a bootable usb with Ubuntu Server on it.

If I try to boot it in UEFI mode (the mode that I've already used to install the current Ubuntu 16.04, needed because otherwise I had problem turning off the pc) the USB doesn't show up at all.

Instead If I try to boot in legacy mode, it shows up but gives the error "No bootable device -- Insert boot disk and press any key" when selected.

Hope I'm not posting it in the wrong section, does someone know what the problem might be?

Comment: what did you use to burn to the USB?

Comment: Did you pick the 64 bit iso image? And how did you create the bootable USB? You should try to repeat writing the USB (eventually with a different tool) after verifying the iso's hash sums.

Comment: Yes there is only the 64bit version, and I used UNetbootin to burn it. I'll try other tools and I'll update the post.

Comment: Faced the same issue while installing windows. This worked for me: https://superuser.com/a/1008330/768336

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your BIOS supports booting from USB - all modern PCs have that, but some may have it disabled in BIOS Settings by default - make sure legacy USB is also on if there is such option.

If that doesn't work or is not the case, then try a different tool to make the USB bootable. For example, 1/10 cases when I used Unetbootin it didn't work, but with Rufus (Windows only) or dd (Linux/UNIX command-line tool) it worked flawlessly each time.